# Correct Postgres full text search indexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, full-text-search, prefix

I'm creating a multi-column full text search index and currently I have this running

```
CREATE INDEX products_search_document ON products
USING gin(to_tsvector('english', style_number || ' ' || brand || ' ' || style_description || ' ' || color));
```

This works great for queries that I'm using like this

```
SELECT * FROM "products"
WHERE (to_tsvector('english', style_number||' '||brand||' '||style_description||' '||color)
      @@ to_tsquery('english', 'G2000'))
```

I'd like to use prefix matching now though so that my query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "products"
WHERE (to_tsvector('english', style_number||' '||brand||' '||style_description||' '||color)
      @@ to_tsquery('english', 'G2000:*'))
```

and when I do run this on my Heroku postgres instance, I'm getting a `Seq Scan on products` instead of an Indexed scan.

What other index would I need to use the prefix matcher in Postgres?

Comment: Have you tried doing

Comment: The query optimizer can choose to ignore an index. It seems both [GIN](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3f510/1) and [GiST](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27da7/1) indexes *can* be used by PostgreSQL for prefix matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing:

```
set enable_seqscan=off;
```

and then running your query to see if it uses it.  I don't see why it wouldn't.  My suspicion is the planner thinks there is not enough specificity for that particular search so thinks a sequential scan is more efficient than a fulltext scan.

That said, I think for prefix queries (where you don't won't stem equivalency to kick in e.g. postgraduate and postgres being considered equivalent) a btree text_pattern_ops, gist(gist_gtrgm_ops) or a gin index (I think spgist might be good but haven't done any metrics on that) on just the concatenated values or even (just on style_number ) if that is all you will be prefixing, would be more efficient than full text.  Your query would not use tsvector, would just use

style_number LIKE 'G5000%'

style_number ILIKE 'G5000%'

and your index would be just on style_number or concatenated values

If you need case insensitivity then use gist(gist_trgm_ops) like covered here:  http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/212-PostgreSQL-9.1-Trigrams-teaching-LIKE-and-ILIKE-new-tricks.html

Comment: Setting `set enable_seqscan=off; ` makes the query now use the index with prefixes and it works.  What effect does doing that have on the rest of my application though?

Comment: Oddly enough actually, doing that in `psql` works but it doesn't not reflect in a rails console or where the code is executing in my app.

Comment: Well the set_enable_seqscan is just to tell the planner that if it can use an index, it should avoid sequential scans and use whatever index it can use.  So now you are back to the question of maybe sequential scan is more efficient for this particular query, because a large percentage of your data would be returned for this stem match.  Compare the speeds of with enable_seqscan off and on and see which is faster.  If index is faster, you'll need to tweak some of the postgresql conf settings to sway the query planner naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, I deleted the index and re-created it...this fixed the issue.

Comment: May it was just the stats were out of date then or I guess they might have been corrupt.  ANALYZE table_name;  usually fixes the stats issue.